# Python TCP (server-client) with VPN

Tags: python, tcp, vpn, openvpn

I am trying to establish a connection between a client and a server that are connected over VPN (opnvpn) as shown in the photo below.

- VPN connection: The openvpn server has the virtual IP of 10.8.0.1 and the openvpn client is the router with IP 10.8.0.6.
- The openvpn server can ping machine 1 that is connected to the router (10.8.0.1 -> 192.168.50.1)
- Similarly, machine 1 can ping the openvpn server over its virtual IP (192.168.50.1 -> 10.8.0.1)
- However, machine 1 cannot ping the openvpn server over its private IP (192.168.50.1 -> 172.31.18.124)

Now, having established connection between both sides, I am trying to establish socket client and server using Python, but it doesnt work. And machine 1 cannot reach the port opened at the 10.8.0.1 server.

So the code I run at at the server side:

```
HOST_SERVER, PORT_SERVER = "10.8.0.1", 8080

server_address = (HOST_SERVER, PORT_SERVER)
while True:
        # Create a TCP/IP socket
        sock_server = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        sock_server.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
        # Bind the socket to the port
        # print >>sys.stderr, 'starting up on %s port %s' % server_address
        sock_server.bind(server_address)
        # Listen for incoming connections
        sock_server.listen(1)
```

At the client side I have this code:

```
HOST_CLIENT, PORT_CLIENT = "10.8.0.1", 8081

sock_client = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
sock_client.connect((HOST_CLIENT, PORT_CLIENT))
message="booom"
sock_client.sendall(message.encode('utf-8'))
received=sock_client.recv(1024).decode('utf-8')
print("Node Connected")
Disconnected= False 
# print("Done")
print(received)
sock_client.close()
```

Note that I tried this on the local network between machine 1 and 2 (both connected to the same router) and it is working fine.

Also I tried to use the telnet command and it is not working.

I am not sure why machine 1 cannot see the port opened at the server side. Am I missing anything?

[image]

Comment: *"Also I tried to use the telnet command and it is not working."* - this is a connectivity problem and not a programming problem, i.e. off-topic. It might just be that there are firewall settings which don't allow the access.

Comment: Both sides can ping each other, hence there is no connectivity issues. It might be due to the openvpn server. You can see in my code that I am using the virtual IP to establish this connection.

Comment: Also there is no firewall settings. Hence: on-topic

Comment: If they can ping each other but the connection to a specific port fails, then there is very likely some firewall involved. If it would be an OpenVPN problem then even a ping would not be possible, since OpenVPN problems manifest at the link and network layer already (i.e. IP is reachable or not) but not at the transport layer (ports). Unfortunately nothing is known about the involved systems so one cannot make more specific recommendations apart from check all firewall settings (client and server).

Comment: Did you ever get this to work? I wrote a similar bit of code and am having the exact same issue, each side can ping each other, and I can even establish TCP connections between the servers, e.g. wget connects but then hangs.

Thanks